# How to configure sitemaps using MVCSiteMapProvider with StructureMap DI

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, structuremap, mvcsitemapprovider

I StructureMap as a way to do DI in my project. I want to create sitemap in my project.
I install `MvcSiteMapProvider MVC4 StructureMap Dependency Injection Configuration` from NuGet.
it requires manual config but I don't know how to config this.

thanks for your helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you installed `MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC4.DI.StructureMap` into your project, it does not require manual configuration. This package is for use when you don't already have DI in your project - it contains a composition root which is meant to be used as the single place to register all of your DI configuration for your entire project.

However, if you installed `MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC4.DI.StructureMap.Modules` into your project, it requires manual configuration. This package is meant to be used in projects that have a pre-existing DI setup. You just need to follow the instructions in the [readme file](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/tree/master/src/MvcSiteMapProvider/CodeAsConfiguration/StructureMap/DI/StructureMap) in order to add it to your existing configuration. The exact procedure and could vary greatly from one project to another, but the readme contains all of the required and optional lines of code that will need to be added. The key is that you need to ensure that only 1 DI container is instantiated for the entire project and that all of the modules are registered with it.

Do note that `MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC4.DI.StructureMap` depends on `MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC4.DI.StructureMap.Modules`, so you can easily downgrade with a single  package manager command.

```
PM> Uninstall-Package MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC4.DI.StructureMap
```

Make sure you don't use the -RemoveDependencies option.